# Good tool to minimize HTML footprint?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, optimization, footprint

Does anyone know a good tool that can be run on a page (for asp.net, for example) to help to minimize the footprint size of the page?

The page will have typical items: HTML, Javascript, etc.

I've heard of Javascript crunchers in the past, that will make the size of the code as compact as possible (and obfuscate it, I suppose).

The goal is to help optimize the page size (make it as small as possible for speed, without changing anything).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could configure your web server to compress the page on the fly (and possibly cache the compressed version) for any client that indicates it can take a gzip or zip (or other) encoding, which is pretty much all of them.

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion.  You should still try to avoid errant HTML code, especially on higher traffic sites, right?

Comment: @pearcewg: How/why would you have errant HTML (which is not code btw, it's markup)? You either write what you intend to show or you don't. I definitely wouldn't have tons of comments, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Well, its not a automatic cleaner-upper, but I like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for optimizing pages.  And the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) can minify your javascript.

If you're really interested in javascript, the keyword is "minify".

Also, look at this question just posted: [HTML and stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299636/good-tool-to-minimize-html-footprint)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Yep, definitely.  I am not an asp.net guy, but things you could look for (as others have said):

- gzip compression for the page - a
  server option
- js: like you said, there are
  minifying options for javascript,
  which in turn can be gzipped as
  well.
- css: there are minifying options
  just like javascript, and can also
  be gzipped.

Our java apps use [pack:tag](http://sourceforge.net/projects/packtag).  Maybe you could find a similar .net replacement.

Yslow, already mentioned, can show what improvements you can make.

Answer (score 2):

Search for some ASP .NET Compression techniques, if you're on IIS6 I recommend you [MbCompression](http://www.codeplex.com/MbCompression),  however if you're running IIS 7 it has great built-in [HTTP compression support](http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2006/06/13/changes-to-compression-in-iis7.aspx), you can define which files get compressed based on their MIME type in your configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of fundamentals:
 IIS saves compressed response of JS/CSS/Html files on disk so, subsequent requests for JS/CSS is served from Disk(bypassing step of compression). While compressed response for ASPX/ASCX are not cached on disk, since response varies from request to request.

Therefore, Best practise is to keep Javascript/CSS in their own files and avoid putting inline CSS/Script in aspx/ascx.

Broadly there are two ways to reduce Page-Size/HTML
1) Compression by webserver/HTTPModule
[Enable IIS 6 HTTP Compression][1]

2) Obfuscation/compression by third party tool - [JASOB](http://www.jasob.com/Features.html)  is my favourite one.

It can also compress/obfuscate javascript/css code from your php/asp.net/perl/jsp/XSLT file. And If like vanila DOS then there's command line interface too.

I have used it in several ASP.NET projects, I just select my webproject directory and JASOB provides nice option to publish obfuscated version of webproject directory. This means it obfuscates javascript/css from all files lying under your webproject directory and yeah it traverses sub directories too. And All of this in one click.

Hope it helps,
Maulik Modi
http://www.jasob.com/Features.html

[1]: - http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2006/08/10/iis-6-compression-quickest-and-effective-way-to-do-it-for-asp-net-compression.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I personally would not sacrifice readability and maintainability for size.

Dynamic web server compression saved me a TON (given text compresses so well), and further optimization would have gained me very little.